# Poisson closure of singular support of a $\mathfrak{g}$ module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, deformation-quantization

This is a question about when two Poisson subvarieties of the dual of a finite dimensional complex Lie algebra agree. I begin with some definitions, which are essentially standard.

**Singular Support**. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $k=\mathbb{C}$, and let $(M,F)$ be a filtered module for it. We have the associated graded module $\operatorname{gr}(M)$ for $S\mathfrak{g}$ and we define $$\operatorname{SS}(M,F):=\operatorname{spec}(S\mathfrak{g}/\operatorname{Ann}\operatorname{gr}(M)).$$

This is closed conical subscheme of $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ called the *singular support*. (Note that we consider this as a scheme which depends on $F$, as opposed to taking the reduced subscheme, which is independent of $F$ if $F$ is *good*.)

**Associated Variety.** We also have the *associated variety*, defined as $$\mathcal{V}(M,F):=\operatorname{spec}(S\mathfrak{g}/\operatorname{gr}\operatorname{Ann}(M)).$$

$\operatorname{V}(M,F)$ is a closed conical *Poisson* subscheme of $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ which contains $\operatorname{SS}(M,F)$.

**Poisson Closure.** We denote by $\operatorname{SS}(M,F)^{!}$ the *Poisson closure* of $\operatorname{SS}(M,F)$, ie the smalles closed Poisson subscheme containing it.

**Question.** When do we have $$\operatorname{SS}(M,F)^{!}=\mathcal{V}(M,F).$$

In particular, is this true if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple and $(M,F)$ is cyclic? Is it true, possibly under some additional hypotheses, if we take the reduced subschemes of both sides?